# Bookmarking options in the select .php function

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="?" method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label> To whom:</label>
                            <select name="target">
                                <option value="A@gmail.com">A</option>
                                <option value="B@gmail.com">B</option>
                                <option value="C@gmail.com">C</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Message:</label>
                            <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="30"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
```

This is a segment of my code and I wish to know how, using something of the likes of a bookmark, to allow a different option to appear in the place of the base A option. I have a page of people to contact that each has a link to the contact us page and I would like the link to automatically place them as the selected option in the select list.
Basically how does one use a bookmark of sorts to make a specific option be the default rather than "A" which would automatically be the default

Comment: Just added a modification to hopefully clear up the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the URL that is taking you to contact us page. Add a parameter in the URL such as `contact_us.php?selected_id=A@gmail.com`.

In contact us page, add the `if isset` statements to make the selection as default.

```
<form action="?" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label> To whom:</label>
                        <select name="target">
                            <option value="A@gmail.com" <?php if(isset($_GET['selected_id'])) if($_GET['selected_id'] == 'A@gmail.com') echo 'selected'; ?> >A</option>
                            <option value="B@gmail.com" <?php if(isset($_GET['selected_id'])) if($_GET['selected_id'] == 'B@gmail.com') echo 'selected'; ?>>B</option>
                            <option value="C@gmail.com" <?php if(isset($_GET['selected_id'])) if($_GET['selected_id'] == 'C@gmail.com') echo 'selected'; ?>>C</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Message:</label>
                        <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="30"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
```